# I can't see the API call's response in the development tools after redirecting to the external website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an API call to build a dynamic link and then redirecting user to the external page.
Recently I noticed that after successfully redirecting user to the built link,
there is nothing in the response tab of chrome development tools.
Is it the way it has to be or I can somehow keep the response in the tab?

```
 endpointFetcher(payload)
      .then((result) => {
        const { token} = result;    
        return window.location.href = `https://mywebsite.com/#/start?genToken=${token}`
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
```

Comment: If you load a new site, the previous site’s diagnostic information is discarded. I believe there’s a “keep log” checkbox (or something named like that) to prevent that.

Comment: If your page is acme.com and your user are redirected to foo.com, What do you need to see?

Comment: You need to enable the "Preserve Logs" option to see that.